# Chain + filter + value returning value is not a function?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I've following array of objects. Each object in the array contain user information.

```
var usersAll = [
  { id: '1', name: 'User 1', selected: true },
  { id: '2', name: 'User 2' },
  { id: '3', name: 'User 3' },
  { id: '4', name: 'User 4' }];
```

I want to extract the users for whom, `selected` is set  to `true`.

This is the code I'm using

```
var selectedUsers = _(usersAll)
 .filter(function(u) {
   return u.selected
 })
 .map(function(u) {
   return u.name
 }
 .value()
```

But for some reason it returns this:

> TypeError: _(...).filter(...).value is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And what is `.value()`? Can it work on arrays

Comment: @Tushar I thought it was a lodash function to get the value of `_chain`?

Comment: So you want to get the `name` of all selected users?

Comment: @Tushar No, just the array of users with `selected = true`.

Comment: You don't need that. Use only `_.filter(usersAll, function(e) {
 return e.selected;
});`

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/dL8dwjts/)

Comment: @Tushar Oh, no. Sorry, yes I need the names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`_.filter`](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) with [`_.pluck`](https://lodash.com/docs#pluck)

1. Filter the array to keep users whose `selected` value is `true`.
2. Use `Pluck` to get the array of values of the `name`.

```js
var usersAll = [{id: '1', name: 'User 1', selected: true},
    { id: '2', name: 'User 2'},
    { id: '3', name: 'User 3'},
    { id: '4', name: 'User 4', selected: true}
];

var selectedUserNames = _.pluck(_.filter(usersAll, 'selected'), 'name');

console.log(selectedUserNames);
document.write(selectedUserNames);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

---

If you don't want to use any library, this can be done in JavaScript using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
var usersAll = [{id: '1', name: 'User 1', selected: true},
    { id: '2', name: 'User 2'},
    { id: '3', name: 'User 3'},
    { id: '4', name: 'User 4', selected: true}
];

var selectedUserNames = usersAll.filter(function(e) {
    return e.selected;
}).map(function(e) {
    return e.name;
});

console.log(selectedUserNames);
document.write(selectedUserNames);
```

Using **EcmaScript 6/ES15** arrow function, it can be done in a single line

```
usersAll.filter(e => e.selected).map(e => e.name);
```

Comment: For Demo purpose, I've added two `selected` users, but if in your case, if **only one user can be selected** at any moment, you can use, `usersAll.filter(e => e.selected)[0].name;`

Comment: The underscore filter call can be simplified to `_.filter(usersAll, 'selected')`

Comment: Thank you @GruffBunny! Didn't knew about that. :)

Answer (score 0):

For those using `4.0.1` and above, in case you chain with `each()`, it seems there could an issue. Check this https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1879

The issue may be something like `Uncaught TypeError: _(...).filter(...).each(...).value is not a function`

The solution would be to explicitly call the `chain` method

```
_.chain(usersAll) // instead of _(usersAll)
 ... // other chaining
 .each(function(u) {
   ...
 }
 .value()
```